# Разрезать картинку на 9 частей

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Надо разрезать картинку на 9 Bitmap'ов, картинка разрезается, но я получаю только левый верхний угол.

Первый метод:

```
private Bitmap GetImageBitmap(Bitmap src, Rectangle rect,int i,int j)
{
    Bitmap Image = new Bitmap(src.Width, src.Height);

    Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(Image);

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            g.DrawImage(src, i, j, rect, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
        }
    }

    return Image;
}
```

Второй метод:

```
private List<Bitmap> SliceImage()
{
    List<Bitmap> slices = new List<Bitmap>();

    Image origin = OriginalPB.Image;
    Bitmap src = new Bitmap(origin, OriginalPB.Width, OriginalPB.Height);
    int k = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(new Point(i, j), GbPazzlesBox.Controls[k].Size) ;
            
            slices.Add(GetImageBitmap(src, rect, i, j));
            k++;
        }
    }
```

Подскажите где моя ошибка?

GbPazzlesBox.Controls[k].Size - размер PictureBoх в которую потом будут выводиться кусочки картинки.

Comment: Используйте метод `Bitmap.Clone`.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov И останется с убеждением, что `DrawImage` не работает.

Answer (score 2):

> Подскажите где моя ошибка?

Ваша ошибка в том, что Вы не выяснили, что означают параметры метода `Graphics.DrawImage`.

[Graphics.DrawImage](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.drawimage?view=net-5.0#System_Drawing_Graphics_DrawImage_System_Drawing_Image_System_Int32_System_Int32_System_Drawing_Rectangle_System_Drawing_GraphicsUnit_)

Comment: Не совсем понимаю о чем Вы. Передаю туда изображение, х, у, прямоугольник и как измерять

Comment: @xantin А теперь прочитайте документацию.